# Android Service Won't Restart On Android 8.1

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have a class extending the service class. I start my service from my MainActivity but the service won't restart on closing the app on android 8.1

In my service class I have the following code:

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

//some code

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

and i start my service like this:

```
  MyService myService = new myService();

    final Intent seriviceIntent = new Intent(this, myService.getClass());

    if (!isMyServiceRunning(myService.getClass())) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                this.startService(seriviceIntent);
            }
        }).start();

    }
    else {

        Log.e("service_log", "service is already running");
    }
```

i also have this entry in my manifest file

> < service android:name=".service.MyService"/>

**On android 7 it works fine but not on android 8.1**

I already tried to start this service without thread or by ui thread but both wasn't working too

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Oreo there are some restrictions on services so you might wanna look at this guide to migrate your service to Oreo:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Or

Have a look at this blog:

https://android.jlelse.eu/keep-those-background-services-working-when-targeting-android-oreo-sdk-26-cbf6cc2bdb7f